# Is there a google API for "People also ask"?

Tags: google-api, google-search-api

Is there any API to access the **people also ask** questions in the google's search result list?

take a look in this example, my search query: **what is google search**

And google presents this other questions:

[google alternative questions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b3B3.png)

Comment: mangools has a questions api. have you tested it?

Comment: tested it right now with the free version, sadly no real questions which fit or google presents are shown by mangools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/related-questions) seems to do it.

Source url : `https://serpapi.com/search.json?q=How+do+you+earn+bitcoins%3F&location=Dallas&hl=en&gl=us&source=test`

Look at the key `related_questions`

```
 "related_questions": [
    {
      "question": "How can I get free Bitcoin?",
      "snippet": "Earn Free Bitcoins Daily with No Investment from InternetOnline Home Income recommend to Earn Free Bitcoins as the number FIVE option because earning bitcoins is really easy and free to join.Check your BTC balance at any time through this address https://blockchain.info/address/<your own BTC address>.KIND ATTN:- You cannot get cash directly from Bitcoins… ... Earning example:More items...•Oct 9, 2018",
      "title": "Earn Free Bitcoins Daily with No Investment from Internet",
      "link": "https://www.onlinehomeincome.in/earn-free-bitcoins-daily.php",
      "displayed_link": "https://www.onlinehomeincome.in/earn-free-bitcoins-daily.php"
    },
    {
      "question": "How do you get bitcoins?",
      "snippet": "Seventh, you can get bitcoins by accepting them as a payment for goods and services or by buying them from a friend or someone near you. You can also buy them directly from an exchange with your bank account. Eighth, there is a growing number of services and merchants accepting Bitcoin all over the world.",
      "title": "5 Easy Steps To Get Bitcoins and Learning How To Use Them",
      "link": "https://www.weusecoins.com/en/getting-started/",
      "displayed_link": "https://www.weusecoins.com/en/getting-started/"
    },
    {
      "question": "Can you make money on Bitcoin?",
      "snippet": "Bitcoin is just like real money. For some strange reason, people tend to think that because Bitcoin is a new form of currency, there is some magical way you can earn Bitcoins or make money from it easily.Oct 10, 2018",
      "title": "How to Get Bitcoins? 12 Ways for Making Money with Bitcoin in 2018",
      "link": "https://99bitcoins.com/earn-bitcoins-fast-free/",
      "displayed_link": "https://99bitcoins.com/earn-bitcoins-fast-free/"
    },
    {
      "question": "What is Bitcoin and how it works?",
      "snippet": "A transaction is a transfer of value between Bitcoin wallets that gets included in the block chain. Bitcoin wallets keep a secret piece of data called a private key or seed, which is used to sign transactions, providing a mathematical proof that they have come from the owner of the wallet.",
      "title": "How does Bitcoin work? - Bitcoin - Bitcoin.org",
      "link": "https://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works",
      "displayed_link": "https://bitcoin.org/en/how-it-works"
    }
```

Comment: thank you. API looks nice. The only thing is that the API is only reporting the minimal set of questions back. I could not find a parameter to tell the api to search for more questions. Any idea - except brute force iteration?

Comment: You will have to iterate through the existing questions, because SerpApi is just a parser for Google results, so if Google doesn't do it, SerpApi won't either

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it suits your question ;)

Comment: SerpApi is super expensive tho.

Comment: @Daniel if you are looking for free one here is the one written in python but you have take care of the hosting for the same. Hope it helps, further attaching the link https://pypi.org/project/people-also-ask/